# Upload image from EC2 to S3

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Please excuse my English, i'm French :)

So, I've to upload images from ec2 to s3.
I'm using the php library but I find it very, very loooong !
So, I've made some search and I've find the s3cmd tool.
But it doesn't work with exec php function :

```
exec("/usr/bin/s3cmd  put –acl-public –guess-mime-type  –config=/var/www/html/.s3cfg   /var/www/html/website/public/img/a/1380098080346/1.jpg  s3://mybucket  2>&1")
```

The output is :

```
ERROR: Can't find a config file. Please use --config option.
```

My config file's owner is apache, and rights are 777 (for testing ;)) but nothing...
I still have the same error...

For information I've followed this page : http://thephpsolutions.wordpress.com/tag/s3cmd/

Have you got an idea ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a typo in your question, but in your exec statement you need to have two dashes before the config:

```
-–config=/var/www/html/.s3cfg
```